# Como forçar o ReactiveForms a validar apenas após tentar enviar os dados?

Tags: angular, typescript, formulário

Tenho um [app simples](https://github.com/arthursiq5/angular-reactive-forms-test/tree/updateOnSubmit) onde fiz alguns testes com os [formulários reativos do Angular](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), e me deparei com a seguinte situação: coloquei um `console.log` na função de validação, e percebi que, ao tentar validar um campo, a cada letra digitada ele tentava validar o campo:

**Função de validação**:

```
export class Validacoes {
    static ValidaCpf(controle: AbstractControl) {
        console.log('validated');
        /* código da validação de CPF */
    }
}
```

**logs do sistema**:

[image: Imagem com dúzias de logs pra apenas um campo]

Aí eu vi na [documentação](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) a seguinte frase:

> We can delay updating the form validity by changing the `updateOn` property from `change` (default) to `submit` or `blur`.

O que quer dizer mais ou menos:

> Podemos atrasar a validação do formulário mudando a propriedade `updateOn` de `change` (padrão) para `submit` ou `blur`.

E eu mudei a propriedade, deixando a criação do meu formulário assim:

```
this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
        /* campos do formulário */
    }, {
        /* outras opções */
        updateOn: 'submit'
    });
```

O que quase resolveu o problema, deixando o console assim:

[image: console quase limpo, com apenas alguns alertas ainda]

Mas ainda me incomoda aquelas três validações antes de poder utilizar o formulário. Como eu as removo?

Há uma build do projeto no [GitHub](https://github.com/arthursiq5/angular-reactive-forms-test/tree/updateOnSubmit) e no [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-test-with-reactive-forms) com ligeiras diferenças, mas ambas apresentando o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendo o comportamento é correto, pois como os valores dos campos são fornecidos inicialmente, o form precisa ser validado (meu entendimento).

Se você observar, o estado do form, vc verá que `this.formulario.pristine` está com valor `true`, ou seja, intocado. Portanto, acredito que você não precise se preocupar com o as validações que ocorrem ao criar o form.